# Difference between "accompany" and "escort"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

I have faced some problems in using these two verbs: "**accompany**" and "**escort**".

How to define which is suitable? Maybe one of them is used only in formal context? They have almost the same meaning so I can't figure out which to choose. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

- **Accompany** means to go *in company* with someone or something (robots), to go together with.
- **Escort** has a sense of providing protection or guidance.

Here's what [The-difference-between](http://the-difference-between.com/accompany/escort) says:

> **Accompany** is a synonym of **escort**. **Escort** is a synonym of **accompany**.
>   As *verbs* the difference between **escort** and **accompany** is that **escort** is to attend with a view to guard and protect; to **accompany** as safeguard; to give honorable or ceremonious attendance to; -- used especially with reference to journeys or excursions on land; as, to escort a public functionary, or a lady; to escort a baggage wagon while accompany is to go with or attend as a companion or associate; to keep company with; to go along with.
>
> As a noun **escort** is a body of armed men to attend a person of distinction for the sake of affording safety when on a journey; one who conducts some one as an attendant; a guard, as of prisoners on a march; also, a body of persons, attending as a mark of respect or honor; -- applied to movements on land, as convoy is to movements at sea.

Answer (score 4):

*X escorts Y* when X travels with Y and remains with Y the entire time, to ensure Y makes it to Y's destination.  It can sometimes carry the implication Y is required to go where X wants under threat of force.  It's unusual for this to be used where X and Y aren't a person or armored/military vehicles.

An *escort* can mean one who escorts someone as a service.  It is also a euphemism for a (typically non-street level) prostitute especially if A) the one being escorted is male, B) the one doing the escorting is female, and C) the context is not any of military, jail/prison, protection, bodyguard, or personal/physical security.  In these contexts you have nothing to worry about.  But be particularly careful with the term "escort service".

*X accompanies Y* just means X will follow Y without the "make sure Y is safe/gets there OK" implication (or other implications) of *escort*.  It's possible for X/Y here to be objects or services, and that general means if you obtain X, Y will be included with it, or that X and Y are part of an inseparable set or group.

Comment: Indeed, if I escort one of my granddaughters to the frozen custard shop, one could also say she accompanies me there.

Answer (score 4):

LawrenceC gives an excellent answer, but I would add that if you *escort* someone, you are typically protecting him from some threat or ensuring that he goes, even if he is not going willingly.

In the recent United Airlines case, the police arrived to *escort* the recalcitrant passenger from the flight.

*Accompany* is connected with *companion*, from `com-`, together, and `panis`, bread, someone you eat with.  If you accompany someone, you are -- at least ostensibly -- going as his friend.